# Force XHR submit of form with Turbolinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, turbolinks

In rails I have table where I'm using jeditable for inline editing.

To return a proper response for jeditable from the form generated I use request.xhr? in my controller like this:

```
    if request.xhr?
      # *** repond with the new value ***
      render :text => params[:order_item].values.first
    end
```

My TD looks like this, I've tried adding data-no-turbolink to body (just to experiment), the td tag and to the button tag (see form below)

```
<td data-no-turbolink="true">
  <span class="editable" data-id="31330" data-name="order_item[actual_price]" title="Click to edit..">46.0</span>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</td>
```

When I click the cell a form is generated by the script like this:

```
<td data-no-turbolink="true">
  <span class="editable" data-id="31330" data-name="order_item[actual_price]">
    <form style="display: inline">
      <input name="order_item[price_override]">
      <button type="submit" >Ok</button>
      <button type="cancel">Cancel</button>
    </form>
  </span>
</td>
```

I think I'm missing some essentional understanding of how Turbolinks is working, is there a way to force this form to submit by XHR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a solution to this, and ended up using another approach.

I send an extra parameter to the action from jeditable that I use in my controller instead of request.xhr?